# ¿Porque no se crea el ImageView en un android 4.4 (API 19) pero si en un android 7.1 (API 25?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

lo traigo de una manera  resumida a esto,tengo un GridLayout que tiene un background como se ve en ambas imagenes, y este contiene 64 ImageView(En el codigo lo hice con 4 solamente para no tener que pegar los 64 ImageView),yo en el Java tengo un vector de imagenes,direccion de imagen,o como se llame,hago un random y segun el numero que toco,le voy asignando a los ImageView segun el orden que tengan en el GridLayout,una imagen del vector gemas.
El programa funciona y le asigna correctamente cuando lo ejecuto en un dispositivo virtual con Android 7.1 en adelante me muestra los ImageView,sus imagenes,el fondo del Grid,todo hermoso,pero cuando lo ejecuto en una versión mas antigua que esa como Android 6.0 o 4.4 como puse en la imagen mas abajo,solo se ve el fondo del GridLayout y no se ven ningun ImageView,busque por todos lados durante 2 dias y no encontre nada,ya no se que puede llegar a ser,si alguno me podria tirar un centro,se lo agradeceria muchisimo,dejo el codigo aca abajo

*XML*

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="8"
android:rowCount="8"
android:layout_weight="64"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/estrella"
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    />
```

*JAVA*

```
package com.example.bejeweledv19;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.Random;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  int matriz[][] = new int[2][2];
  int[] gemas = {R.drawable.red, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.green, 
  R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.purple, R.drawable.yellow};
  GridLayout grid;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    grid =  findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <=7; j++) {
            int num = random.nextInt(6);
            matriz[i][j] = num;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <=7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <=7; j++) {
            ImageView imagen = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i * 2 + j);
            imagen.setImageResource(gemas[matriz[i][j]]);
        }
    }
```

Asi se ve en Android 7.1 (API 25)
[image: Android 7.1 (API 25)]

Asi se ve en Android 4.4 (API 19)
[image: Android 4.4 (API 19)]

Answer (score 1):

creo que el problema es de la libreria no estas usando una support library entonces no funciona en versiones anteriores.

Cambia la version de la libreria gridlayout, mas especificamente pone esto en tu build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.+
//cuidado con esto incluso en algunas versiones de esta libreria hay bugs y puede no funcionar
```

y despues cambia en el xml `GridLayout` por `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`

finalmente deberias cambiar el import en la clase. Remplaza esto `import android.widget.GridLayout;` por `import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout;`

Espero que esto te resuelva el problema.